# how to write to GCS with a ParDo and a DoFn in apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Using `apache_beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems` how to write to GCS with a ParDo and a DoFn ?? I am already getting output in csv format from a pardo, do i need  to write another pardo to write it to gcs or can i directly import a module to write it directly to gcs ? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an example [here](https://github.com/gxercavins/dataflow-samples/blob/master/quick-draw/convert.py) where I write b64-encoded images to GCS using `apache_beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems`. The last step of the pipeline takes `b64` as the PCollection containing two fields `key_id` and `image` and applies the ParDo:

```
b64 | 'Save images' >> beam.ParDo(WriteToSeparateFiles(known_args.output))
```

where `known_args.output` is a GCS base path and `WriteToSeparateFiles` is as follows:

```
class WriteToSeparateFiles(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, outdir):
        self.outdir = outdir
    def process(self, element):
        writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(self.outdir + element['key_id'] + '.png')
        writer.write(element['image'])
        writer.close()
```

With `filesystems.FileSystems.create()` I have control over the destination path. For the base path I use the parameter we passed to the function and I use the `key_id` of each element to generate meaningful file names. Finally, I append the `.png` extension as I am writing images.

I use `writer.write(element['image'])` to save the contents of the `image` field for each file and close the stream with `writer.close()`.

Comment: perfect ! It helped but there's one issue instead of appending my result my output gets overwritten .could you please help me with that?